# How do I identify if the water bottle is of a safe material for my children?

Tags: drinking

From my understanding, BPA-Free plastic water bottle is safe for my little ones. However, some manufacturer does not provide any information on their water bottles but I would like to buy one because they have very cute cartoon design which my little ones love them.

So, are there any other methods that I can test the water bottle so that I know that they are safe for my little ones? (I heard that as long as you put hot water to the water bottle and the water bottle does not change shape or dis-colored, it is deem safe but would like to hear suggestions from experts out there. Thanks.)

Comment: What you heard is wrong. There are many rigid plastics which will not discolor or soften when heated which do still contain BPA.

Comment: So, are there any method that we parent can perform on the plastic water bottle to ensure that they are safe? (I heard stories that some merchants will stick "BPA free" stickers on their products even their products are not "BPA free". So, would like to know if there are any methods for parents like us which we can perform on the water bottle to ensure that it is BPA-free.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

US Department of Health and Safety has some information:

http://www.hhs.gov/safety/bpa/

To reduce the potential transfer of BPA to the foodstuffs:

- avoid containers not labeled 'bpa-free' (ideal)

Of if you don't know:

- avoid hot foods/liquids in containers
- avoid scratched containers

In general, if safety is a concern, I'd let federal agency/mandatory safety labeling trump printed cartoon graphics.

Comment: I heard stories that some merchants will stick "BPA free" stickers on their products even their products are not "BPA free". So, would like to know if there are any methods for parents like us which we can perform on the water bottle to ensure that it is BPA-free.

Comment: Where do you live? In many countries, there'd be laws regarding that. I'd be sure to go with name brands and avoid the dollar-store offerings.

Comment: oh...and no DIY method short of taking it to a lab for analysis.

Comment: Taking to lab for analysis will be quite costly. (I dun have extra $ to spend cause most are invested in my little ones.) However, would be looking for solution that can DIY test the plastic water bottle.

Comment: There is no DIY way.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to remember that BPA has been used in everyday plastics, including baby bottles, for decades and absolutely no ill effects in humans have been linked to everyday BPA exposure. The concern with BPA is purely hypothetical, so BPA is avoided in food packaging today out of an overabundance of caution.

There are more important things to worry about: Are your kids getting their immunizations? Has the child safety seat you are using (if you use one) had any recalls? Are your kids brushing their teeth often enough? These are all things that pose a far greater danger to your children's wellbeing than BPA.

Comment: While true, 'purely hypothetical', while accurate, may be downplaying it a bit. We do know it causes issues in various animal's systems. Still, valid points...there are typically bigger issues to worry about.

Comment: Wait a minute, Dan, may I interpret from your answer that BPA products are safe for my little ones? Nowadays, it is so hard to be a parent cause some said BPA is dangerous while some said BPA is safe. All I know is that I don't want to endanger my little ones with things that can cause them cancer or illness.

Comment: @Jack: The general way that "safety" is worked out, is a) what negative side effects have been seen in a lab where they often boost the dose until they get an effect, and b) what negative side effects have been seen among actual kids.

For example, paracetamol is seen to be safe during pregnancy because mothers used it for years before anyone thought to check if it was safe, which meant they could just look at the current crop of kids and go "well, they seem fine".

With something like thalidomide, same principle, tragically different outcome.

Comment: @Jack: With BPA, they've proven that if they give a large enough dose to lab animals it's dangerous, and that's where the concerns come from.
Counter to that, it's been used in plastics for years, and there's not been a conclusive study on what effect that's had on kids.
Counter to *that*, the concerns were only raised recently, and conclusive studies take time.

Comment: I'd like to add in an answer I gave on the Skeptics site:

http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/does-regularly-drinking-from-a-plastic-container-cause-cancer/2207#2207

There are published studies which are raising more concerns about the presence of BPA (and phthalates) in bottles, etc.

-1 for not bothering to reference the claim that 'the concern with BPA is purely hypothetical' when, in fact there ARE concerns - especially for children (ie early onset of puberty, etc)

Comment: @Darwy: First, this isn't the skeptics SE; answers aren't expected to be thoroughly referenced. Second, I looked at your answer, and the sources you cite there (that I could access) confirm what I have said here: none of them showed a definitive -- or even probable -- link to any negative health effects in humans. One of the sources you cited states, "we do not yet have any clear cause–effect relationships in humans". And as you stated in your answer, animal tests showing harm (such as cancer) involve "LARGE" doses of BPA. So, yes, as of this time the concern is hypothetical.

Comment: @DanMoulding 

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19478717

"BPA has shown to cause PP in pubertal girls"

Where PP is precocious puberty

So no, the concern is no longer hypothetical.

Comment: @Darwy: Nice try. That is a poorly written meta-analysis. It is poorly written not only because of the numerous grammatical mistakes, but also because of the outright misleading statements. When that "study" states "BPA has shown [sic] to cause PP in pubertal girls", it gives the impression that this was shown in *human* girls. The authors fail to make clear that, in the cited study, the subjects were girl **mice** not human girls (the relevant study, #62 referenced in Table 3, can be read here: http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v401/n6755/full/401763a0.html). Thank you, try again.

Comment: So you're saying that mice models cannot be used to compare with human results? That's not really true. Mice/rats have many systems which are comparable to ours and they show adverse effects from the same compounds we do. http://ehp03.niehs.nih.gov/article/fetchArticle.action?articleURI=info%3Adoi%2F10.1289%2Fehp.9804  and http://endo.endojournals.org/content/152/6/2150.abstract

Comment: @Darwy: No, I said harm to humans from typical BPA exposure is hypothetical. Animal models often exhibit biological responses that are different from humans, too, so the fact that BPA can have significant biological effects in mice doesn't, by itself, tell us anything about how it will affect humans. That said, animal models can be a good starting point for formulating hypotheses about human reactions. Until BPA is shown to cause harm in humans, under typical exposure, then any hypothesized harm it may cause to humans from plastic bottles is just that: hypothetical.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is contact the Food & Drug Administration for your country and ask them about this product.

If it's unsafe for children, that could be a major issue, which they'd need to investigate.

If it's safe, they'll let you know.

Comment: I'd like an explanation of the downvote...